# First time access to Outlook Web Access calendar after ADFS authentication redirects to mailbox

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

I am building an external web application that authenticates against ADFS. My current Exchange environment is a hybrid configuration of Office 365 with a Exchange 2013 hybrid server.

Here are the steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Open external web app
2. Authenticate via ADFS login page then redirect back to web app
3. Click on direct link to OWA calendar: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#path=/calendar

From there, it will go through the OWA loading screen and open the mailbox instead of the calendar. This only occurs after the very first time accessing OWA after authentication; any attempts after that will correctly route to the calendar.

Is there a way to correctly route to the calendar every time?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?path=/calendar

This link is redirected to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#path=/calendar after going through the OWA login process.

After the user has logged both links appear to work the same.